# Add arbitrary series with legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a bunch of data - three timeseries (model group means), coloured by group, with standard deviation represented by geom_ribbon. By default they have a nice legend on the side. I also have a single timeseries of observations, that I want to overlay over the plot (without the geom_ribbon), like this:

```
df <- data.frame(year=1991:2010, group=c(rep('group1',20), rep('group2',20), rep('group3',20)), mean=c(cumsum(abs(rnorm(20))),cumsum(abs(rnorm(20))),cumsum(abs(rnorm(20)))),sd=3+rnorm(60))
obs_df <- data.frame(year=1991:2010, value=cumsum(abs(rnorm(20))))
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=mean)) + geom_line(aes(colour=group)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=mean+sd, ymin=mean-sd, fill=group), alpha = 0.2) +geom_line(data=obs_df, aes(x=year, y=value))
```

But the observations does appear on the legend, because it's not coloured (I want it black). How can I add the obs to the legend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create a combined data frame of `df` and `obs_df`:

```
dat <- rbind(df, data.frame(year = obs_df$year,  
                  group = "obs", mean = obs_df$value, sd = 0))
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=year, y=mean)) +
geom_line(aes(colour=group)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=mean+sd, ymin=mean-sd, fill=group), alpha = 0.2) +
scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "black")) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", NA))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes! Thank you, exactly what I wanted. (btw, I fixed the year typo in the question, if you feel like updating the graph :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you made an error with your construction of 'obs_df'. If you create it with `year = 1991:2010` it makes more sense in the context of the rest of the data and it gives you the plot you are hoping for with the `ggplot` call unchanged.

Comment: That was a typo in the question, fixed, thanks.. The plot works fine, the problem is that the obs line (in black) does not appear in the legend.

Comment: Did you also mean to type "does not appear"?